# Stages FSA BB30 Power Meter on Cannondale SI BB30A Crankset

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, power, cannondale

I have a Cannondale CAAD12. It has a Cannondale SI crankset. The frame's bottom bracket is BB30A.

My question is, can I fit a Stages FSA BB30 Power Meter on the non drive side?

My concerns:

- BB30A is 5mm wider than BB30. Will this affect my q-factor (lateral distance between cranks) or can I get around it by changing spacers.
- Will the Stages FSA actually fit on the Cannondale Spindle?

**UPDATE**
This [chart](https://www.c-bear.com/bbchart.pdf) suggests that I should be ok with Stages FSA BB30. Does anyone agree?

Comment: 2 questions: Are you planning to replace both sides of your crankset? Or just use the FSA non-drive side on your SI crank? And second, why do you need a new bottom bracket?

Comment: Not planning on replacing both. I don't need a new bottom bracket. The chart shows how to convert between form factors right? I assumed the chart therefore tells me that fsa and bb30a are compatible without the need for a converter?

Comment: That chart does not appear to say that the 2 frame standards are compatible. However, if you are only adding the LH crank arm from Stages to your SI crankset, the FSA Stages is not the correct choice. That is a matter of the spline pattern on the BB spindle, which is specific for each brand of crank. Stages does make an SI power meter.

Comment: If you are planning on replacing both sides of the crank, then you can use an FSA crank in your frame, with an additional 5mm spacer on the non drive side.

Comment: Thanks. Wanna write that up as the answer and I'll mark as accepted?